# How to use arc co-ordinates from .slib file to draw an arc in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview

I am trying to generate various `gate symbols` ( AND,NOT,XNOR,MUX etc) by reading `.slib` file.
But I faced a problem while reading an `arc` related co-ordinate from `.slib` file.

> I am not understanding how to use those co-ordinates and draw an arc ?
> The format of an arc in .slib file is confusing.

Here is the example:
[image]

`.slib` format for an `arc` and for `line`

```
line (66 * SCALE, 80 * SCALE, 0 * SCALE, 80 * SCALE); 
line (94 * SCALE, 70 * SCALE, 62 * SCALE, 70 * SCALE);
              .
              .

arc (145 * SCALE, 100 * SCALE, 94 * SCALE, 70 * SCALE,94.9268 * SCALE,126.774 * SCALE);     
arc (94 * SCALE, 130 * SCALE, 145 * SCALE, 100 * SCALE,94.9268 * SCALE, 73.2256 * SCALE);    
arc (61 * SCALE, 130 * SCALE, 61 * SCALE, 70 * SCALE,8.75 * SCALE, 100 * SCALE);
```

1st line says draw an arc from O (145,100) to  F(94,70)
2nd line says draw an arc from L(94,130)  to  O(145,100)
3rd line says draw an arc from K(62,30) to E(62,70)

I tried to draw an arc by using 1st 4 co-ordinates from line ( but do not know how to use remaining 2 co-ordinates ? )

```
 QPainterPath path;  // arc from L --->  F 
 path.moveTo(94,70);
 QRect bound1 (44,70,102,60);
 path.arcTo(bound1,90,-180);
        
 QPainterPath path1;  // arc from K ---> E
 path1.moveTo(62,70);
 QRect bound2 (42,70,40,60);
 path1.arcTo(bound2,90,-180);
```

And I got following output :

[image]

But,

> Input lines to OR gate are not attached to
> 1st arc.
> I am using only first four co-ordinates. How to use remaining 2 co-ordinates to draw an arc ?

So how to use all given co-ordinates from`.slib` to draw an `arc` ?
Note : SCALE is defined at the start of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the first two coordinate pairs are two points on an imaginary circle and the third pair is the center of that circle. Together, those describe a circle arc section. For this to work with `arcTo`, we construct a `QRectF` bounding the circle, ie with the given center and side `2*radius`.

Thus, the following ought to work:

```
QPointF from, to; // first and second coordinate pair
QPointF center; // third coordinate pair

// Bounding rectangle is a square around center.
QLineF lineFrom{center, from};
QLineF lineTo{center, to};
qreal radius = lineFrom.length();
QRectF bounding{ center - QPointF{radius, radius}, center + QPointF{radius, radius}};

// Use QLineF to calculate angles wrt horizontal axis.
qreal startAngle = lineFrom.angle();
qreal sweep = lineFrom.angleTo(lineTo);

QPainterPath path;
path.moveTo(from);
path.arcTo(bounding, startAngle, sweep);
```